# aplay -l doesn't see my loopback sound card using snd_aloop

Tags: alsa

This question is similar to:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/598377/aplay-l-doesnt-see-my-loopback-sound-card

Basically I have an embedded system with kernel and I am root.

```
# uname -a
Linux openmiko 3.10.14 #7 PREEMPT Sat Sep 5 21:33:15 UTC 2020 mips GNU/Linux
```

I see the loopback card:

```
# cat /proc/asound/cards 
 3 [Loopback       ]: Loopback - Loopback
                      Loopback 1
```

But aplay -l gives me nothing:

```
# aplay -l


********************   WARNING   *******************************
Warning! aplay uses ALSA emulation instead of the native OSS API
****************************************************************

aplay: device_list:268: no soundcards found...
#
```

```
# lsmod 
Module                  Size  Used by    Tainted: G  
snd_aloop              12002  0 
snd_pcm                68453  1 snd_aloop
snd_page_alloc          3810  1 snd_pcm
snd_timer              18670  1 snd_pcm
snd                    39168  3 snd_aloop,snd_pcm,snd_timer
v4l2loopback           22369  2 
sensor_jxf23            9136  1 
tx_isp                337860  3 
sinfo                  12972  0 
#
```

More details:

```
# cat /proc/asound/
Loopback/  cards      modules    timers
card3/     devices    pcm        version
# cat /proc/asound/pcm 
03-00: Loopback PCM : Loopback PCM : playback 2 : capture 2
03-01: Loopback PCM : Loopback PCM : playback 2 : capture 2
# cat /proc/asound/modules 
 3 snd_aloop
# cat /proc/asound/devices 
 33:        : timer
 96: [ 3]   : control
112: [ 3- 0]: digital audio playback
113: [ 3- 1]: digital audio playback
120: [ 3- 0]: digital audio capture
121: [ 3- 1]: digital audio capture
```

Comment: You are trying to load an ALSA driver on a system that is actually using OSS drivers. You have to use an OSS loopback driver (if it exists).

Answer (score 0):

Managed to figure it out.

There seems to be some sort of issue when I load a v4l2rtspserver that
utilizes the LIVE 555 library.
I believe it might have been claiming the loopback device or something
along those lines. When I changed the order in which I started some of
the programs aplay -l started showing the device. Still not entirely
sure what might have been the cause here.